# How can we use ProgressBar with ExecutorService to engage user when data is loading in background

Tags: android, executorservice

How can we use ProgressBar with ExecutorService to Engage user while data is loading in the background in the android studio.
i want to fetch data from external sqlite database.it works but takes times to load data and visible to the user.asynctask is deprecated i use ExecutorService to load in background.Here i want to use ProgressBar while data is loading in the background.The progressbar shows nullpointexception error.

**Mainactivity.java**

```
  public class Vocab extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        String idd, word, wmean, wsynon, wsmean;
        TableLayout tLayout3;
        TableRow tbrow;
        OpenDatabase od;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        View view;
        ProgressBar pro;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_vocab);
    
            pro=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            pro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                private Cursor cursor;
    
                @Override
                public void run() {
    
                    OpenDatabase myDbHelper = new OpenDatabase(Vocab.this);
                    try {
                        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
                    }
                    try {
                        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                        throw sqle;
                    }
    
                    this.cursor=myDbHelper.viewData();
    
                    //just 4 progress
    
                    TableLayout tLayout3 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.vtable);
    
                    TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(Vocab.this);
                    //tbrow0.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowlist));
                    tbrow0.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                    TextView tv0 = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                    tv0.setText(" No ");
                    tv0.setTypeface(tv0.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    tv0.setTextSize(18);
                    tv0.setTextColor(rgb(0,72,186));
                    //tv0.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                    tv0.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
                    tbrow0.addView(tv0);
    
                    TextView tv1 = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                    tv1.setText("   Word      ");
                    tv1.setGravity(0);
                    tv1.setTextSize(18);
                    tv1.setTextColor(rgb(0,72,186));
                    tv1.setTypeface(tv1.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    //tv1.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                    tv1.setPadding(45,0,0,0);
                    tbrow0.addView(tv1);
    
                    TextView tv2 = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                    tv2.setText("Meaning    "+"    ");
                    tv2.setTypeface(tv2.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    tv2.setTextSize(18);
                    tv2.setTextColor(rgb(0,72,186));
                    //tv2.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                    tv2.setPadding(63,0,0,0);
                    tbrow0.addView(tv2);
    
                    TextView tv3 = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                    tv3.setText("Antonym    ");
                    tv3.setTypeface(tv3.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    tv3.setTextSize(18);
                    tv3.setTextColor(rgb(0,72,186));
                    // tv3.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                    tv3.setPadding(75,0,9,0);
                    tbrow0.addView(tv3);
    
                    TextView tv4 = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                    tv4.setText("         Meaning      ");
                    tv4.setTextSize(18);
                    tv4.setTextColor(rgb(0,72,186));
                    tv4.setTypeface(tv4.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    tv4.setPadding(13,0,9,0);
                    tbrow0.addView(tv4);
    
                    tLayout3.addView(tbrow0);
    
    
       // progressbar
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pro.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
                        }
                    });
    
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        String idd, word, wmean, wsynon, wsmean;
                        TableRow tbrow;
    
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
    
    
                            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                                this.idd = cursor.getString(0);
                                this.word = cursor.getString(1);
                                this.wmean = cursor.getString(2);
                                this.wsynon = cursor.getString(3);
                                this.wsmean = cursor.getString(4);
    
                                for(int l=0;l<=cursor.getColumnCount();l++)
                                {
                                    TableRow tablerow = new TableRow(Vocab.this);
                                    this.tbrow=tablerow;
                                    // tbrow.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowlist));
                                    tbrow.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                                    TextView tid = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                                    tid.setText( " "+this.idd+" ");
                                    tid.setTextColor(rgb(0,0,0));
                                    tid.setPadding(9,0,0,0);
                                    // tid.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                                    this.tbrow.addView(tid);
    
                                    TextView tbase = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                                    tbase.setText(" " + this.word);
                                    tbase.setTextColor(rgb(175,0,42));
                                    tbase.setPadding(45,0,0,0);
                                    // tbase.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                                    tbase.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 140, 0));
                                    this.tbrow.addView(tbase);
    
                                    TextView tmean = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                                    tmean.setText(" " + this.wmean+" ");
                                    tmean.setPadding(61,0,0,0);
                                    //tmean.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                                    tmean.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 140, 0));
                                    this.tbrow.addView(tmean);
    
                                    TextView tpast = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                                    tpast.setText(" " + this.wsynon);
                                    tpast.setPadding(75,0,9,0);
                                    //tpast.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                                    tpast.setTextColor(rgb(175,0,42));
                                    this.tbrow.addView(tpast);
    
                                    TextView tparti = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                                    tparti.setText("     " + this.wsmean +"     ");
                                    tparti.setPadding(32,0,9,0);
                                    //tparti.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                                    tparti.setTextColor(rgb(175,0,42));
                                    this.tbrow.addView(tparti);
                                }
                                tLayout3.addView(this.tbrow);
    
                               // p.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
    
    
                            }
                        }
                    });
    
    
                }
    
    
    
            });
    
        }
    
    
    }
```

**Xml Layout**

> ```
> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
>   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_margin="2dp"
>     tools:context=".Vocab">
>
>     <ProgressBar
>         android:id="@+id/progressBar"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
>
>     <ScrollView
>         android:id="@+id/scrollView"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="452dp"
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar"
>         app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.246">
>
>         <HorizontalScrollView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_margin="6dp"
>             android:orientation="horizontal"
>             android:padding="5dp">
>
>             <TableLayout
>                 android:id="@+id/vtable"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:padding="0dp" />
>
>         </HorizontalScrollView>
>
>     </ScrollView>
>
> </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not accurate, I think this may still help you

```java
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //...do my long joob
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for Replying and correction. i tried it but shows an error in logcat                                          attempt to invoke virtual method.android widget.progressbar.setvisibility(int) on null object reference

Comment: There is an error because you did not initialize the progressBar. If you show me your code or explain clearly what you want to do I can help you

Comment: i intialized the progressbar but i don't know why it show nullpointexception.                 i mean that i want to fetch data from external sqlite database.it works but takes times  to load data and visible to the user.                                                                                                              asyncktask is deprecated i use ExecutorService to load in background.Here i want to use ProgressBar while data is loading in the background.

Comment: Can you share your code plz ?

Comment: yeah sure i edited the question you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

**Mainactivity.java**

```
public class Vocab extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        String idd, word, wmean, wsynon, wsmean;
        TableLayout tLayout3;
        TableRow tbrow;
        OpenDatabase od;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        View view;
        ProgressBar pro;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_vocab);
    
           pro=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            pro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                private Cursor cursor;
    
                @Override
                public void run() {
    
                    OpenDatabase myDbHelper = new OpenDatabase(Vocab.this);
                    try {
                        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
                    }
                    try {
                        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                        throw sqle;
                    }
    
                    this.cursor=myDbHelper.viewData();
    
                    //just 4 progress
    
                    TableLayout tLayout3 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.vtable);
    
                    TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(Vocab.this);
                    //tbrow0.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowlist));
                    tbrow0.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                    TextView tv0 = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                    tv0.setText(" No ");
                    tv0.setTypeface(tv0.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    tv0.setTextSize(18);
                    tv0.setTextColor(rgb(0,72,186));
                    //tv0.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                    tv0.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
                    tbrow0.addView(tv0);
    
                    TextView tv1 = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                    tv1.setText("   Word      ");
                    tv1.setGravity(0);
                    tv1.setTextSize(18);
                    tv1.setTextColor(rgb(0,72,186));
                    tv1.setTypeface(tv1.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    //tv1.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                    tv1.setPadding(45,0,0,0);
                    tbrow0.addView(tv1);
    
                    TextView tv2 = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                    tv2.setText("Meaning    "+"    ");
                    tv2.setTypeface(tv2.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    tv2.setTextSize(18);
                    tv2.setTextColor(rgb(0,72,186));
                    //tv2.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                    tv2.setPadding(63,0,0,0);
                    tbrow0.addView(tv2);
    
                    TextView tv3 = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                    tv3.setText("Antonym    ");
                    tv3.setTypeface(tv3.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    tv3.setTextSize(18);
                    tv3.setTextColor(rgb(0,72,186));
                    // tv3.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                    tv3.setPadding(75,0,9,0);
                    tbrow0.addView(tv3);
    
                    TextView tv4 = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                    tv4.setText("         Meaning      ");
                    tv4.setTextSize(18);
                    tv4.setTextColor(rgb(0,72,186));
                    tv4.setTypeface(tv4.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    tv4.setPadding(13,0,9,0);
                    tbrow0.addView(tv4);
    
                    tLayout3.addView(tbrow0);
    
    
       // progressbar
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pro.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
                        }
                    });
    
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        String idd, word, wmean, wsynon, wsmean;
                        TableRow tbrow;
    
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
    
    
                            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                                this.idd = cursor.getString(0);
                                this.word = cursor.getString(1);
                                this.wmean = cursor.getString(2);
                                this.wsynon = cursor.getString(3);
                                this.wsmean = cursor.getString(4);
    
                                for(int l=0;l<=cursor.getColumnCount();l++)
                                {
                                    TableRow tablerow = new TableRow(Vocab.this);
                                    this.tbrow=tablerow;
                                    // tbrow.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowlist));
                                    tbrow.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                                    TextView tid = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                                    tid.setText( " "+this.idd+" ");
                                    tid.setTextColor(rgb(0,0,0));
                                    tid.setPadding(9,0,0,0);
                                    // tid.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                                    this.tbrow.addView(tid);
    
                                    TextView tbase = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                                    tbase.setText(" " + this.word);
                                    tbase.setTextColor(rgb(175,0,42));
                                    tbase.setPadding(45,0,0,0);
                                    // tbase.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                                    tbase.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 140, 0));
                                    this.tbrow.addView(tbase);
    
                                    TextView tmean = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                                    tmean.setText(" " + this.wmean+" ");
                                    tmean.setPadding(61,0,0,0);
                                    //tmean.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                                    tmean.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 140, 0));
                                    this.tbrow.addView(tmean);
    
                                    TextView tpast = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                                    tpast.setText(" " + this.wsynon);
                                    tpast.setPadding(75,0,9,0);
                                    //tpast.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                                    tpast.setTextColor(rgb(175,0,42));
                                    this.tbrow.addView(tpast);
    
                                    TextView tparti = new TextView(Vocab.this);
                                    tparti.setText("     " + this.wsmean +"     ");
                                    tparti.setPadding(32,0,9,0);
                                    //tparti.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.trowcell));
                                    tparti.setTextColor(rgb(175,0,42));
                                    this.tbrow.addView(tparti);
                                }
                                tLayout3.addView(this.tbrow);
    
                               // p.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
    
    
                            }
                        }
                    });
    
    
                }
    
    
    
            });
    
        }
    
    
    }
```

**XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    tools:context=".Vocab">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="452dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.246">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/vtable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="0dp" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).